# Java Swing button freezes program

Tags: java, swing, button, freeze, event-dispatch-thread

I wrote a simple application in Swing that writes text to a file. Here is my main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class WritingTextToFileApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new MainFrame("Application");

            frame.setSize(500, 400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is the other class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

public MainFrame(String title) {
    super(title);
    //Set Layout Manager
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //Create Swing Components
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JButton button = new JButton("Add");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
             File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Vincent Wen\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
            try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
                br.write(input);
                br.newLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to write to file:" + file.toString());
            }
        }

    });
    //Add Swing components to conent pane
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    c.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

}

Whenever I press the button, the program freezes and nothing happens. Is there something wrong with the code? I am new to Swing so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're blocking the thread that manages the GUI, and waiting to read (console) input from the user. You should use an [input dialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) instead. That will bring up a window to enter the info in, and won't freeze the GUI.

Comment: `String input = scanner.nextLine();` is blocking operation and it will be executed in EDT (event dispatcher thread which also handles Swing GUI). So since `scanner` is supposed to read from `System.in` your GUI thread will wait until you provide some data via System.in (which usually is console).

Comment: Are you trying to get the text from your TextArea or have people type into the console to then write to `Test.txt`?  If you want to get the text from your TextArea do `textArea.getText()` and then write to your file from that text.  Split it up like this `String lines[] = textArea.getText().split( "\\n" );` and transverse over lines.

Answer (score 3):

Swing runs the actions synchronously in the same thread that's handling the GUI input and rendering. That means that when you click the button, it waits for the action listener to complete running before it goes back to handling input and drawing the GUI. In this case, it's effectively stopping the GUI from running until you type something into the console.

You can use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to run it asynchronously so that it continues running the GUI while it runs the action.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you press the button, java expects to read data from System.ini (console).

Try to start your application by using the java command on a console. Then enter some text in the console after pressing the button and press enter. Your program you work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by using textArea.getText() instead of using scanner.